# error creating a bluebird promise with requirejs for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, requirejs, bluebird

I am developing a chrome extension that makes use of 'chrome.storage.local' and am trying to create a promise out of the chrome.storage.local.get() async function, which I would like to be able to throw exceptions from as well as reject/resolve. I've tried testing this with the below implementation, but am seeing an error which from the console logs seems to be from the "`readLocalStorageObj("prefs").then(function(item) {`" line (the error is shown below after the code).

```
require([
    "libs/bluebird"
],
function(Promise) {
    function readLocalStorageObj(itemName) {
        var localReadResult = Promise.method(function(item) {
            console.log("localReadResult():", item);
            // if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            //  throw new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            // }

            if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item).length > 0) {
                console.log('in if part');
                return item;
            }
            else {
                console.log('in else part');
                // throw new Error("my test exception");
                return undefined;
            }
        });

        chrome.storage.local.get(itemName, localReadResult);
        return localReadResult;
    };

    readLocalStorageObj("prefs").then(function(item) {
        console.log('success', item);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log('fail', e);
    }).error(function(e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }).catch(ChromeRuntimeError, function(e) {
        console.log('catch', e);
    }).finally(function(a) {
        console.log('finally', a);
    });
});
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function Promise$_method() {
>           var value;
>           switch(arguments.length) {
>           case 0: value = tryCatch1(fn, this, void 0); break;
>           case 1: value = tryCatch1(fn, this, arguments[0]); break;
>           case......n'

I can't quite seem to figure out what the cause for this is ,and would really appreciate any help with this.

TIA

Comment: What are you trying to do? Using `Promise.method` doesn't make sense in this situation.

Comment: I'm basically trying to get a Promise from the async read chrome.storage API. Any other suggestions on how to go about getting a Promise in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Try creating the promise like this:

```
require([
    "libs/bluebird"
],
function(Promise) {
    function readLocalStorageObj(itemName) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            chrome.storage.local.get(itemName, function(item) {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                }

                if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item).length > 0) {
                    return resolve(item);
                }
                reject(new Error("empty item"));
            });
        });
    }

    readLocalStorageObj("prefs").then(function(item) {
        console.log('success', item);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log('fail', e);
    }).error(function(e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }).catch(ChromeRuntimeError, function(e) {
        console.log('catch', e);
    }).finally(function(a) {
        console.log('finally', a);
    });
});
```

---

However if you need to use promises with extension callback conventions a lot this will result in a lot of boilerplate.

To avoid boilerplate, you can define a generic promisification function for this convention:

```
function promisfyChrome(fn, ctx) {
    return function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        var self = ctx || this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            args.push(function(value) {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                    return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                resolve(value);
            });
            fn.apply(self, args);
        })
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
require([
    "libs/bluebird"
],
function(Promise) {
    var chromeLocalStorageGet = promisifyChrome(chrome.storage.local.get, chrome.storage.local);
    function readLocalStorageObj(itemName) {
        return chromeLocalStorageGet(itemName).then(function(item) {
            if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item).length > 0) {
                return item;
            }
            throw new Error("empty item");
        });
    }

    readLocalStorageObj("prefs").then(function(item) {
        console.log('success', item);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log('fail', e);
    }).error(function(e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }).catch(ChromeRuntimeError, function(e) {
        console.log('catch', e);
    }).finally(function(a) {
        console.log('finally', a);
    });
});
```

---

Btw:

```
    readLocalStorageObj("prefs").then(function(item) {
        console.log('success', item);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log('fail', e);
    }).error(function(e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }).catch(ChromeRuntimeError, function(e) {
        console.log('catch', e);
    }).finally(function(a) {
        console.log('finally', a);
    });
```

Is in this case equivalent to:

```
    readLocalStorageObj("prefs").then(function(item) {
        console.log('success', item);
    }).catch(Error, function(e) {
        console.log('fail', e);
    }).error(function(e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }).catch(ChromeRuntimeError, function(e) {
        console.log('catch', e);
    }).finally(function(a) {
        console.log('finally', a);
    });
```

As you can see the first `catch` already catches any kind of error so the other catches are never triggered. You will want to do it in the opposite way - more specific catch handlers first and more general ones last.

Also, using `.then` with 2 functions is really hard to read so it's not recommended. Prefer `.then(fn).catch(fn2)` over `.then(fn, fn2)`

Comment: I was using something similar to this initially however the catch() block never seemed to get invoked (and as I mentioned I wanted to distinguish between exceptions and explicit failures). For e.g. when I throw a new TypeError("empty item") it sort of silently failed. Only reject and resolve seem to work. Any idea why?

Comment: @source.rar the `.error()` is same as `.catch([ExplicitRejection], function(e){` so it will already qualify as catching the explicit `reject(chrome.runtime)` call. If you wan't it to qualify as implicit, do `throw chrome.runtime`

Comment: @source.rar never mind I just noticed you had a catch-all handler in the first .then. That is really hard to notice - I suggest you never use 2 handlers at the same time when using `.then` and just use separate `.catch`. Anyway - the catch all handler is eating all exceptions so the `.error()` and `.catch(ChromeRuntimeError)` are never triggered

Comment: by the catch-all are you referring to the reject handler? If so isn't that just that a reject handler and not a catch-all? If I understand correctly a catch-all would be a catch(function(e){}) chained to the above?

Comment: @source.rar yes, I also edited my answer at the bottom hope it helps

Comment: Without the reject handler (as shown in your bottom edit). I now get a "Possibly unhandled Error: undefined" on a reject(). And I'm beginning to think that the chrome APIs do not propagate throws from them.

Comment: @source.rar neither `.error()` nor `.catch(ChromeRuntimeError)` qualify as handlers when `undefined` is thrown - so there is no handlers and the error is unhandled thus the warning.

Comment: Yeah, so a reject handler is needed within the first then (as there seems no other way to handle it). And if I replace the reject() with a  throw (which was how I was trying to test the throw), it never reaches  any of the handlers. Which I think means that the Chrome API callback is perhaps not propagating the throw.

Comment: @source.rar well no it isn't, `undefined` being thrown is a bug in your code not a runtime error that you can handle. You need to fix the bug so that `undefined` is not thrown in the first place.

Comment: actually undefined isn't being thrown in this case. I'm just doing a reject() without any arguments (which is effectively undefined) because I don't want to return an empty object and have the caller figure out its empty.

Comment: @source.rar I see, you should never throw a non-error like `undefined`. You should instead throw a `NotFoundError` or `EmptyItemError` or something.

Comment: @Esailija promisifyChrome works like a charm, should be accepted answer!